# MySQL Access Read in FreeBASIC

Tags: mysql, freebasic

I have a problem developing this example code.

This code would help to understand how communication with a MySQL server works in FreeBASIC, Currently I have been able to find some examples in C but I don't understand how to adapt everything in FreeBASIC.

In the part where the content should be displayed gives me an error when compiling and I have no idea how to do it.

```
#Include Once "mysql\mysql.bi"
#define NULL 0



    Dim Shared URLServer As String
    Dim Shared SVRDataBase As String
    Dim Shared SVRUser As String
    Dim Shared SVRPassword As String

    DIM Shared Conn As MYSQL PTR
    DIM Shared MySQLOut As MYSQL_RES PTR
    DIM Shared Row As MYSQL_ROW

Declare Function MySQLRead(MyQuery As String, MyWork As String) As Integer    


Function MySQLRead(MyQuery As String, MyWork As String) As Integer    
  
    URLServer = "localhost"
    SVRDataBase = "test"
    SVRUser = "testuser"
    SVRPassword = "testpassword"

    MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM `test_table`"
    Conn = mysql_init(NULL)
    
    if (Conn = 0) then Print "Error  Conn= 0"
    if mysql_real_connect(Conn, URLServer, SVRUser, SVRPassword, SVRDataBase, 0, NULL, 0) = NULL then Print "Real Connect = 1"
    if mysql_query(Conn, MyQuery) then Print "Query = 1"

    MySQLOut = mysql_store_result(Conn)

    if MySQLOut = 0 then Print "No out"
    Return 1
   
End Function  
    
Sub Reading()
    DIM TotalCol As Integer
    DIM TotalRow As Integer
    Dim CiR As Integer
    Dim CiC As Integer
    Dim NE as Integer
    
    
    IF MySQLRead("SELECT * FROM `cape_anagrafica`", "read") = 0 then Print "Errore"
    
    TotalCol = mysql_num_fields(MySQLOut)
    TotalRow = mysql_num_rows(MySQLOut)
    
    print TotalRow
    print MySQLOut(0)

    

    mysql_free_result(MySQLOut)
    mysql_close(Conn)
End Sub

Reading()

end 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is written right what is wrong is just the display, treat the mysql object as an array while it is a type object.

Below I will rewrite the correct code.

```
#Include Once "mysql\mysql.bi"
#define NULL 0

    Dim Shared URLServer As String
    Dim Shared SVRDataBase As String
    Dim Shared SVRUser As String
    Dim Shared SVRPassword As String

    DIM Shared Conn As MYSQL PTR
    DIM Shared MySQLOut As MYSQL_RES PTR
    DIM Shared Row As MYSQL_ROW

Declare Function MySQLRead(MyQuery As String, MyWork As String) As Integer    


Function MySQLRead(MyQuery As String, MyWork As String) As Integer    
  
    URLServer = "localhost"
    SVRDataBase = "test"
    SVRUser = "testuser"
    SVRPassword = "testpassword"

    MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM `test_table`"
    Conn = mysql_init(NULL)
    
    if (Conn = 0) then Print "Error  Conn= 0"
    if mysql_real_connect(Conn, URLServer, SVRUser, SVRPassword, SVRDataBase, 0, NULL, 0) = NULL then Print "Real Connect = 1"
    if mysql_query(Conn, MyQuery) then Print "Query = 1"

    MySQLOut = mysql_store_result(Conn)

    if MySQLOut = 0 then Print "No out"
    Return 1
   
End Function  
    
Sub Reading()
    DIM TotalCol As Integer
    DIM TotalRow As Integer
    Dim CiR As Integer
    Dim CiC As Integer
    Dim NE as Integer
    
    
    IF MySQLRead("SELECT * FROM `cape_anagrafica`", "read") = 0 then Print "Errore"
    
    TotalCol = mysql_num_fields(MySQLOut)
    TotalRow = mysql_num_rows(MySQLOut)
    
    print TotalRow
' remove print MySQLOut(0) because is not array
' and put this cicle FOR NEXT
' Remember Row[] is not a array if you want store the data in array you have ' to convert it 
    
    For CiR = 0 to TotalRow -1 step 1
    Row = mysql_fetch_row(MySQLOut)
      For Cic = 0 To TotalCol - 1 step 1
        if Row[CiC] = NULL then print "| NULL "; else print "| "; *Row[CiC]
      Next CiC
    Next Cir

    mysql_free_result(MySQLOut)
    mysql_close(Conn)
End Sub

Reading()

end 0
```

Comment: Its work in same way in linux too ?

Comment: yes, But its no header for DOS  for mysql you have to use sqli